# Is it possible to craete a lookup field to your own list?

Tags: lookup-column

sp 2010: Is it possible to craete a lookup field to your own list? I try it now, but the lookup field is empty.

My target is to have list items which refer to other list items. Like main and sub items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, you set the target list to the same list:

[image]

Comment: I did, but my lookup column is emtpy when I try to fill a value.

Comment: Can you edit your post and include a screenshot of column settings and screenshot of trying to fill a value?

Comment: I found the issue. I was showing the Title column in my lookup field. The title field was empty for all listitems:) I change it to another column which is not empty. Now I can see it.